# Terminate called after throwing an instance - C++ error?

Tags: c++, string, erase, letters

In this program I have a string which I pass as a parameter to a function. I want the function to erase all adjacent letters from a string containing only letters from a-z, always ordered alphabetically. For example if i enter aaabbccd, the program ought to output ad. I want to ask why the program stops working?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
vector<char> rez;
string reduce_string(string s)
{
    for(int i=0; i<s.length()-1; i++)
    {
        if(s[i]==s[i+1])
        {
            s[i]=s[i+1]='0';
            s.erase(i);
            s.erase(i+1);
        }

    }
    return s;
}
int main()
{

    string s;
    cin >> s;
    cout<<reduce_string(s);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Can you also state some example inputs with your desired output?

Comment: [Learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and it should become obvious.

Comment: Nice `return`...

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` is inside the loop - the loop will only run on the first character then return.

Answer (score 0):

After the first `erase(i)` all the characters shift one left and the indices change. Instead of calling `s.erase(i+1)` you have to call again `s.erase(i)` to not try to access beyond the end of the string:

```
s.erase(i);
s.erase(i);
```

or just `s.erase(i, 2)`.